# Rails Can't Find Gem Railties (>=0.a)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/local/bin/rails:232in ‘<main>' 
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.9/rubygems.rb23982in ‘activate_bin_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.9/rubygems.rb22892in ‘find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= e.a)    
with executable rails (Gem emNotFoundExcegtion)
```

One fix that works is doing **rvm reset** but that changes my ruby version back to 2.5.1. The reason I got this error in the first place was because I upgraded my ruby version to 3.0.0.

Now, everytime I try to run a rails command like **rails s** I get the error as seen in the picture above.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I've tried many solutions from other people who had the same problem but to no success. It seems like from the picture above, rails is looking at the directory ruby/2.5.0/ even though I'm on ruby version 3.0.0. I just installed rvm so I'm not sure how to tell rails to stop looking at the old ruby installation.

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5XzH.png)

Comment: I downvoted because an [image of your exception isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do gem install rails to fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).